# Query regarding Expandable subfile

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

In load all subfile the max number of data that can be loaded in the buffer is 9999, is there any similar space limitation in case of an expandable subfile or a single page subfile?

Answer (score 1):

An expandable subfile is basically a load-all subfile. Programmatically, you just add more and more records to it beyond SFLSIZ, and the OS takes care of proper expansion of the memory area. It handles scroll-back for you.

A single-page subfile displays just one single page of data. The programmer is responsible for erasing and filling it accordingly, handling the scrolling keys, and so on. Thus, there are no limitations whatsoever.

Also see my [Github project](https://github.com/PoC-dev/as400-sfltemplates-german) (German).

Comment: So the limit for an expandable subfile is also 9999 similar to loadall subfile?

Comment: @KunalRoy - Yes.

Comment: If that is the case then what is the advantage of using an expandable subfile over a loadall subfile?

Comment: Initial content is displayed faster. No need to wait until all records are loaded and then the display will be updated. The older the machine, the more apparent the effect.